# Extracting data from JSON file, keyerror problem

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract certain positions from AWS pricelist, but I am keeping getting the below error code. Is there an error with JSON structure ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Python/python2.py", line 5, in <module>
    for r in data['SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X']:
KeyError: 'SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X
```

**JSON FILE**

```
"SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X" : {
  "sku" : "SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X",
  "productFamily" : "Compute Instance",
  "attributes" : {
    "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
    "location" : "Asia Pacific (Singapore)",
    "locationType" : "AWS Region",
    "instanceType" : "r5n.8xlarge",
    "currentGeneration" : "Yes",
    "instanceFamily" : "Memory optimized",
    "vcpu" : "32",
    "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon Platinum 8259 (Cascade Lake)",
    "clockSpeed" : "2.5 GHz",
    "memory" : "256 GiB",
    "storage" : "EBS only",
    "networkPerformance" : "25 Gigabit",
    "processorArchitecture" : "64-bit",
    "tenancy" : "Shared",
    "operatingSystem" : "Windows",
    "licenseModel" : "No License required",
    "usagetype" : "APS1-BoxUsage:r5n.8xlarge",
    "operation" : "RunInstances:0102",
    "capacitystatus" : "Used",
    "dedicatedEbsThroughput" : "5000 Mbps",
    "ecu" : "NA",
    "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : "No",
    "intelAvxAvailable" : "No",
    "intelAvx2Available" : "No",
    "intelTurboAvailable" : "No",
    "normalizationSizeFactor" : "64",
    "preInstalledSw" : "SQL Ent",
    "servicename" : "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud"
  }
```

**Python code:**

```
import json

with open('index (5).json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for r in data['SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X']:
        print (r)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: can you show me your data variable ?

Comment: Considering the JSON you shared is you `data` variable, I don't see a problem. I just run your code it worked fine. It printed: `sku`, `productFamily` and `attributes`. Was that what you wanted to print? If you wanted to print the attributes, you should have used `data['SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X']['attributes']`.

Comment: The only thing I need to point out is that you would need some extra curly brackets in your json for this to properly work, otherwise you will get syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some curly brackets around the whole thing, the json below parses properly

```
{
    "SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X": {
        "sku": "SJQU8C5FNVFYMK7X",
        "productFamily": "Compute Instance",
        "attributes": {
            "servicecode": "AmazonEC2",
            "location": "Asia Pacific (Singapore)",
            "locationType": "AWS Region",
            "instanceType": "r5n.8xlarge",
            "currentGeneration": "Yes",
            "instanceFamily": "Memory optimized",
            "vcpu": "32",
            "physicalProcessor": "Intel Xeon Platinum 8259 (Cascade Lake)",
            "clockSpeed": "2.5 GHz",
            "memory": "256 GiB",
            "storage": "EBS only",
            "networkPerformance": "25 Gigabit",
            "processorArchitecture": "64-bit",
            "tenancy": "Shared",
            "operatingSystem": "Windows",
            "licenseModel": "No License required",
            "usagetype": "APS1-BoxUsage:r5n.8xlarge",
            "operation": "RunInstances:0102",
            "capacitystatus": "Used",
            "dedicatedEbsThroughput": "5000 Mbps",
            "ecu": "NA",
            "enhancedNetworkingSupported": "No",
            "intelAvxAvailable": "No",
            "intelAvx2Available": "No",
            "intelTurboAvailable": "No",
            "normalizationSizeFactor": "64",
            "preInstalledSw": "SQL Ent",
            "servicename": "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can use online linter to check for parsing errors (e.g https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to debug this is to open an interactive interpreter session and look at what keys are present:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_file = open('index (5).json')
>>> data = json.load(json_file)
>>> data.keys()
```

you might want to cast `data.keys()` as a list (ie. `list(data.keys())`) if you want to manipulate it at all. But at least this will show you what `json.load` thinks the keys are.